# Phrasing the future... In 5 years I think I will

Tags: traducción, futuro

I'm trying to say the phrase

> "In two years I think I will work in a lab".

I've been playing around with my spanish book and I've come up with the phrase

> "En dos años creo voy a trabajo en un laboratorio."

But I'm not sure this is the correct usage of ir a syntax. My thinking that this is correct is because voy a means "going to" and then work in a lab.

I've never been here before and I'm just picking up the language, so thanks for any and all feedback.

Here is the context of the entire paragraph.

> En la Universidad, mi especialización es la química. Me gusta la
>   química porque es interesante. Las clases son difíciles, pero la tarea
>   es fácil. En dos años creo voy a trabajo en un laboratorio.

Comment: The phrase is, in structure, correct. But there are grammar mistakes, check the conjugation!!

Answer (score 3):

The correct construction would be "voy a trabajar" (tú vas a trabajar, ella va a trabajar, etc.)

The periphrastic future is "Ir a" + infinitive. The only one you needed to conjugate was the "ir", the infinitive is left invariable for all persons.

Also, "creer" needs a "que" when a clause follows.

Thus, "creo que voy a trabajar en un laboratorio".

Edit: user1676874 makes a fair point, I took for granted this was the construction you wanted to use but forgot about warning you about the levels of certainty.

Answer (score 3):

While you are correct when you say `voy` means `going to`, it's odd to translate it like that when there is no actual `going to` in your original sentence.

A better approach would be:

> En dos años creo que trabajaré en un laboratorio.

Also remember that in English you use `will` to change a verb to its future tense, so in this case it should also change in your Spanish translation, hence changing `trabajar` for `trabajaré`, `voy a` of course, doesn't require this step as it happens with `going to` in English as well.

Comment: This answer is correct. As side note, if you were translating `In 2 years I'm going to work in a lab` it would be like `En 2 años voy a trabajar en un laboratorio`; however, the most used form in spanish would be `En 2 años estaré trabajando en un laboratorio` (In 2 years I will be working in a lab).

Comment: Agreed with this one. and with the comment above me